# netlogo 3D similar keyword to random-float in 2D?

Tags: netlogo

I'm currently working on adapting "The Game of Life" code in 3D for a final in my CS class for high school, and I'm looking for a keyword similar to "random-float" that will have the same effect in netlogo. For reference, here is the link to the netlogo manual for the "random-float" keyword: http://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/dict/random-float.html

if anyone could help me out, it would be very much appreciated.

Comment: I'm a bit confused on the question because it could be asking about the other "random" functions found in the NetLogo dictionary. Are you trying to find an integer based random, a random with a different probability distribution, or a random that allows you to specify the range?

Comment: So what have you tried?

Comment: So, in the original "Game of Life" model in the model library, one of the lines that determines the density of the patches, which is "random-float". I look it up in the netlogo dictionary, and admittedly, I don't entirely understand it. I tried writing it as is in 3D, but it will always create patches at the same density. I think what I'm looking for is a probability distribution, in order for it to work.

Comment: When you say create patches are you referring to coloring them or some other operation, making them invisible? Could you add a code snippet of your latest version that creates the patch with varying density?

Answer (score 2):

I think you're okay to convert this more or less directly to 3D without using a different primitive- `random-float` or `random` should still do the trick. Essentially, in the 2D version the density is determined by getting each cell to randomly draw a number between 0 and 100, and compare that to the value in the `initial-density` slider. If the number drawn is less than the `initial-density`, the cell is "born." So, you can basically do the same thing in 3D- with this simplified setup:

```
to setup
  ca
  ask patches [ 
    ; if a random number between 0 and 100 is less than
    ; 5, become a "live" cell. Otherwise, become a dead cell.
    ifelse random-float 100 < 5 
    [ cell-birth ]
    [ cell-death ]   
  ]
  reset-ticks
end

to cell-birth
  set pcolor green
end

to cell-death
  set pcolor black
end
```

That gives something like:

[image]

So, to get the density to vary you can just modify the `5` (or add a slider as was done in the original 2D life. If I instead do 50:

```
to setup
  ca
  ask patches [ 
    ifelse random-float 100 < 50 
    [ cell-birth ]
    [ cell-death ]   
  ]
  reset-ticks
end
```

I get a much denser 3D world:

[image]

I hope that helps!

Comment: Thank you so much! It helped out a lot. I realized after a short while trying this that I was using a greater than, instead of a less than, so that was a problem, but this works flawlessly!